# Sending parameters to RESTful ArcGIS site and returning values to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json, rest, ssis, arcgis

I am migrating a query from RPG (old AS400 hijinks) to SQL Server, which luckily, uses vanilla SQL that easily translates over.  However, the issue I'm running into is that the query makes a callout to an ArcGIS site that has a form which accepts the parameters and returns values.  I have tried to make this work following the WSDL instructions found on many sites and incorporating SSIS, but the ArcGIS site is not a web service/.asmx site per se (as I see it).  So here are the players:

- SQL Server 2012
- SSIS (possibly, as I've had no luck so far)
- Can use either Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 (I have mainly experience in VB, none in C#)
- ArcGIS site which accepts the following parameters, zipcode1, zipcode2, date, and vehicletype
- The site allows for the return values in html or json format and
- The site has two buttons allowing for GET or POST

How do I receive values back into my query, or at the very least, populate a table based on the query results which are the parameters that need to be sent to the site?

Comment: ArcGIS Server exposes its services through both REST and SOAP. What you describe sounds like the REST endpoint. It's pretty easy to use. Documentation is online at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r300000054000000 . Your main tasks will be to 1) send an HTTP request to the REST endpoint and 2) parse the JSON response. Both are pretty simple in C# so I'm guessing they're simple in VB.NET too.

Comment: @GaryS. I agree, so it looks like for my situation that I would use a SSIS web service task, but every tutorial points takes me to a wsdl that gives me an error message.  What's the proper path to start on?  Is it downloading the SDK for .NET or WPF in my case (as I don't have these yet and may be hamstrung by permission restriction from work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after waiting weeks for a meeting to discuss this issue with an internal ArcGIS 'team', it turns out that the report being migrated was not to be using this method to get results in the first place.  The same data now occurs on a separate database within our instance, and I only need to query the three tables involved with location to get results for reporting.